# How to distort image sub area only in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opencv, canvas

I need to distort the image sub area from the selected shape in android application. I have searched online there are some techniques around it, we can use android canvas directly or open cv for that.

We can use image warping to do the desired effect using android canvas.
Here is the code for that: https://github.com/jameswhite7/android_trapezoidal_imagewarp

I have also tried in OpenCV using this code but its not working.

```
val originalBitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.my_image)
val rect: RectF = RectF(100f, 100f, 300f, 300f) // define the rectangle to be warped

// Convert the bitmap to a Mat object
val originalMat: Mat = Mat(originalBitmap.height, originalBitmap.width, CvType.CV_8UC4)
Utils.bitmapToMat(originalBitmap, originalMat)

// Convert the selected rectangle to a Mat object
val roiMat: Mat = originalMat.submat(Rect(rect.left.toInt(), rect.top.toInt(), rect.width().toInt(), rect.height().toInt()))

// Convert the Mat objects to grayscale
val originalGrayMat: Mat = Mat(originalMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1)
Imgproc.cvtColor(originalMat, originalGrayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
val roiGrayMat: Mat = Mat(roiMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1)
Imgproc.cvtColor(roiMat, roiGrayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)

// Calculate the optical flow between the two grayscale Mats
val flow: Mat = Mat()
Video.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(originalGrayMat, roiGrayMat, flow, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

// Apply the optical flow to the selected rectangle
val warpedRoiMat: Mat = Mat(roiMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4)
Imgproc.remap(roiMat, warpedRoiMat, flow, Mat(), Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR)

// Copy the warped rectangle back to the original image
warpedRoiMat.copyTo(originalMat.submat(Rect(rect.left.toInt(), rect.top.toInt(), rect.width().toInt(), rect.height().toInt())))

// Convert the Mat object back to a bitmap
val warpedBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalMat.cols(), originalMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
Utils.matToBitmap(originalMat, warpedBitmap)
```

Here is another version that I have tried:

```
// Load the original bitmap image
val originalBitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.my_image)

// Convert the bitmap to a Mat object
val originalMat: Mat = Mat(originalBitmap.height, originalBitmap.width, CvType.CV_8UC4)
Utils.bitmapToMat(originalBitmap, originalMat)

// Define the points for the source (original) and destination (warped) rectangles
val srcPoints = MatOfPoint2f(
        Point(0.0, 0.0),
        Point(originalMat.cols().toDouble(), 0.0),
        Point(originalMat.cols().toDouble(), originalMat.rows().toDouble()),
        Point(0.0, originalMat.rows().toDouble())
)
val dstPoints = MatOfPoint2f(
        Point(originalMat.cols() * 0.1, 0.0),
        Point(originalMat.cols() * 0.9, 0.0),
        Point(originalMat.cols().toDouble(), originalMat.rows().toDouble()),
        Point(0.0, originalMat.rows().toDouble())
)

// Calculate the perspective transformation matrix
val perspectiveTransform: Mat = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(srcPoints, dstPoints)

// Apply the perspective transformation to the original image
val warpedMat: Mat = Mat(originalMat.size(), originalMat.type())
Imgproc.warpPerspective(originalMat, warpedMat, perspectiveTransform, originalMat.size())

// Convert the warped Mat object back to a bitmap
val warpedBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(warpedMat.cols(), warpedMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
Utils.matToBitmap(warpedMat, warpedBitmap)
```

I want to add full bitmap behind the sub area so that when user apply distortion it can be applied on that.

Need help in applying this functionality.

Thanks